# How to deploy a pywebio application using Flask, (so that I can deploy in websites like heroku etc)

Tags: python, flask

I have my pywebio application running on localhost.

```
`
import openai
import pyperclip

from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio.output import *
from pywebio.session import *
from pywebio.pin import *

import pywebio
openai.api_key = "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"


def home():
  put_image('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/OpenAI_Logo.svg',width='50%',height='50%')
  evenorodd()
def evenorodd():
    engines_dict={"text-davinci-003":3200, "text-curie-001":1600, "text-babbage-001":1600, "text-ada-001":1600}
    myinp=input_group("ASK GPT-3",[
      input("", placeholder='Enter any question', required=True,help_text="",name="question"),
    radio("Choose an engine",name="engine", options=["text-davinci-003", "text-curie-001", "text-babbage-001", "text-ada-001"],required=True)])
    put_text(myinp["question"]).style('color: green; font-size: 20px;font-weight: 600; padding-top:20px')

    
    with put_loading(shape='grow',color='success'):
      response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine=myinp["engine"],
        prompt=myinp["question"],
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=engines_dict[myinp["engine"]],
        top_p=1,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0
      )   
      toast("Success")  

    put_button("copy",onclick=lambda:(toast("Copied"),pyperclip.copy(response.choices[0].text)),color='success',outline=True).style('float: right')
    put_text(response.choices[0].text).style('background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);padding: 10px;border-radius: 8px;')
    put_button("Ask another Question",onclick=evenorodd).style('position: relative;bottom: 0') 
    

pywebio.start_server(home,port=90, debug=True)

`
```

How to convert this into Flask and deploy ?? I tried to search on net but they are rendering various templates in Flask. Help me with this

I tried running on my localhost, but many errors are occurring. Anyone help me with this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you may need to reset your api key since you post it in code

Comment: yeah I did @WangWeimin

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**
Heroku no longer supports free dynos. [Here](https://help.heroku.com/RSBRUH58/removal-of-heroku-free-product-plans-faq#:%7E:text=For%20non%2DEnterprise%20users%2C%20free,will%20be%20converted%20to%20mini%20.) 
 This implies you will have to explore other options such as [Pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com),[Vercel](https://vercel.com),Railway, e.t.c 
I will be using vercel for this question.

---

### Flask part:

Add these to your code;

```
from flask import Flask
from pywebio.platform.flask 
import webio_view 


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "your_secret_key" 


def main():
     def home(): 
          put_image(....)
          evenorodd()
      def evenorodd():
             #your blocks of code for the function goes here 
  
      #call the home function here
      home()

#set the url rule
app.add_url_rule('/', 'webio_view', webio_view(main),methods=['GET','POST'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
      app.run(debug=False)
```

The above should work properly by default on localhost and a random port.

---

### Project structure and files:

```
  ----project folder
    |----/api
    |     |--<appname>.py
    |----requirements.txt
    |----vercel.json
```

The *requirements.txt* should specify all the python modules to be installed.
The *vercel.json* should look as shown below:

```
{
 "builds":[
       {
         "src": "api/<appname>.py",
         "use": "@vercel/python"
       }
   ],
   "routes": [
        {
         "src": "/(.*)",
         "dest": "api/<appname>.py"
       }
   ]
}
```

With these so far, your project is due for deployment. Deploy the project to [github](https://github.com)

---

### Deploying to Vercel:

Go to [Vercel](https://vercel.com) and create an account or sign in with github, gitlab or bitbucket.
Once your *vercel* account is verified and set up; on the dashboard **Add New Project** you should see option to import from *github* repository.
Connect to your *github*, select the *repo* you want to deploy and set up the necessary such as project name (default is *repo* name),domain,environment variables e.t.c. Then deploy, it should take few seconds for deployment to complete. There should be a link to your web app that looks like this: **https://your_project_name.vercel.app**
**Congratulations**

You may find this tutorials useful:

- *[vercel + Mongodb](https://matiasfuentes.hashnode.dev/how-to-deploy-a-flask-web-app-on-vercel)*
- *[flask to vercel using CLI](https://dev.to/andrewbaisden/how-to-deploy-a-python-flask-app-to-vercel-2o5k)*